Lebesgue integral via Product-measure of Lebegue-Measures
I got a question about product measures. I found an interesting statement in the Book "Taylor, Introduction to Measure and Integration" which I want to quote:
"Suppose ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu$) is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{L}, \nu)$ denotes the real line with Lebesgue measure on it an $\tau$ is the product measure $\mu\times \nu$ defined on the product fiedld $\mathcal{H}$ in $\Omega\times \mathbb{R}$. Then if $E∈\mathcal{F}$ and $f\colon E \to\mathbb{R}^+$ is non-negative, $f$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable over $E$ if and only if $Q(E,f)∈\mathcal{H}$ and in this case
$$
∫_E f\,d\mu = \tau(Q(E,f))
$$
where $Q(E,f):=\{(x,y): x∈ E, y∈\mathbb{R}, 0≤ y≤ f(x)\}$ (this is the ordinate set)."
In another book about Lebesgue-Integration (Weir, Lebesgue Integration and Measure, p. 134) I am asked to prove the statement: If $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, non-negative and Lebesgue-measurable, then $f$ is integrable if and only if the ordinate set has finite Lebesgue-measure $\lambda^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I this case: $\int f = \lambda^2(Q(\mathbb{R},f))$. This means that the Lebesgue-integral of such a function can be defined via the Lebesgue-measure of the ordinate set.
But there is my problem: If I take $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ the product field $\mathcal{H}$ isn't the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue-measuarble sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because the first one isn't complete while the Lebesgue-measure is.  So if I now take a Lebesgue-measurable function that has a measurable ordinate set with finite Lebesgue-measure it would be integrable while it need not to be integrable if I use the statement quoted. Do you know where my problem is? Thank you very much!
